# Django Hosted on Apache: Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding Python runtime state:

Tags: python, django, apache

I am trying to host a Django app on Apache 2.4. The service won't start and produces the folowing error

```
[Thu Oct 28 13:12:37.898096 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5144:tid 628] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 7828
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'python'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = 'C:\\apache24\\bin\\httpd.exe'
  sys.base_prefix = 'C:\\Users\\myuser\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = 'C:\\Users\\myuser\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = 'C:\\apache24\\bin\\httpd.exe'
  sys.prefix = 'C:\\Users\\myuser\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310'
  sys.exec_prefix = 'C:\\Users\\myuser\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310'
  sys.path = [
    'C:\\Users\\myuser\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python310.zip',
    '.\\DLLs',
    '.\\lib',
    'C:\\apache24\\bin',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00000fa0 (most recent call first):
  <no Python frame>
[Thu Oct 28 13:12:38.413708 2021] [mpm_winnt:crit] [pid 5144:tid 628] AH00419: master_main: create child process failed. Exiting.
```

The server ran before I did all the configurations and went to the "it worked" screen.

I think it has to do with either my httpd-host conf

```
<Directory /some/path/project>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost 
    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    ErrorLog "C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/app.error.log"
    CustomLog "C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/app.access.log"  combined
    WSGIScriptAlias /  "C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/app/wsgi_windows.py"
    <Directory "C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/app/EmployeeKiosk">
        <Files wsgi_windows.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    Alias /static "C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/app/static"
    <Directory "C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/app/static">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>  
</VirtualHost>
```

OR
My wsgi_windows py

```
import os
import sys
import site

# Add the site-packages of the chosen virtualenv to work with
site.addsitedir('C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/app/appEnv/Lib/site-packages')




# Add the app's directory to the PYTHONPATH
sys.path.append('C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/app')
sys.path.append('C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/app/appEnv')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'app.settings'
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "app.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I am using a virtual enviroment and there aren't a whole lot of clear instructions on how to handle that.

Edit: I should mention this is a windows system. according to https://code.google.com/archive/p/modwsgi/wikis/ConfigurationDirectives.wiki#WSGIPythonHome  You can not use WSGIPythonHome to override the  PYTHONEXECUTABLE path. But, the default should be correct as it match what the error lists.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, with Windows, you don't need to use WSGIPythonHome. Apache ignores this. What I had to do was add and environment variable PYTHONHOME and point to the global python dir - see below:

[image]

I reloaded apache, and it worked no problem.